# How do I create a script to automatically capture/copy all download links in a specific browser?

Tags: browser, hyperlink, download, capture

How do I create a script to automatically capture/copy all download links in a specific browser?
Additionally is there any way to automatically cancel every download that starts in my web browser(Opera or Chrome)?

Comment: there are free browser plugins for this

Comment: I've looked. Cant find any.